# Grid Box Shift between divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a mini grid post layout using css. But i have a problem with divs. I have try it in this **[demo](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/jVPMZv)** page. And I do not get the shape I want. I want to make it like the screenshot

[image]

I try it like this CSS codes:

```
.div {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  background-color:#1d1f20;
}

.div:nth-child(1){
  width:180px;
  padding-top:180px;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.div:nth-child(2){
  width:180px;
  padding-top:180px;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.div:nth-child(3){
  width:400px;
  padding-top:400px;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.div:nth-child(4){
  width:180px;
  padding-top:180px;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.div:nth-child(5){
  width:365px;
  padding-top:180px;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

.div:nth-child(6){
  width:180px;
  padding-top:180px;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
</div>
```

How can i get the screenshot within css ? Anyone can help me here ?

Comment: Only CSS or you can use JS/Jquery?

Comment: @paolo.basso99 I just want to make it with css only. I know i can do it with js but if possible i want to do it just in css.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lot of solutions:

**Solution one:**

Use the new `column-count`. **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/9um3pqLz/2/)**.

[Check](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) the browser compatibility.

**Solution two:**

Use `display:inline-block;`. **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/tt3vufdu/)**.

[Check](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) the browser compatibility.

**Solution three:**

Using `flexbox`. **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/akt0aswv/)**.

[Check](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) the browser compatibility.

**Solution four:**

Use JQuery, I suggest you the [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin (usually used for galleries) . [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/d9e37eg5/1/).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, i had to restructure your html to achive that here is the link:http://codepen.io/saa93/pen/ENjNgy

```
<style>
body,html {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  max-width:1010px;
  min-height:400px;
  margin:0px auto;
}

.div {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  background-color:#1d1f20;
}

.div:nth-child(1) {
  background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0;
  float: left;
  width: 370px;
}


.div:nth-child(3){
  width:180px;
  float:left;
}
.div:nth-child(1) > .div:nth-child(1){
  background-color:#1d1f20;
  width:180px;
  padding-top:180px;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.div:nth-child(1) > .div:nth-child(2){
  width:180px;
  padding-top:180px;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.div:nth-child(1) > .div:nth-child(3) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 185px;
  width: 365px;
}

.div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 370px;
  width: 400px;
}
.div:nth-child(3) > .div:nth-child(1){
  width:180px;
  padding-top:180px;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

.div:nth-child(3) {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
}
.div:nth-child(3) > .div:nth-child(2){
  width:180px;
  padding-top:180px;
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="div">
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
   </div>
  <div class="div"></div>


  <div class="div">
    <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps :)